# How can I copy fonts from images in Gimp 2.8.0?

Tags: windows, images, gimp, image-editing

Question/Title sums it up.

How can I copy fonts from images in Gimp 2.8.0? I'm using/running the Windows version of Gimp.

I have dozens of images that I'd like to copy fonts from just to experiment/tinker with.

Here's a sample image:

[image: sample]

Comment: What kind of images? What do you mean by "copy"? You want to take the pixels of the text in the raster image and somehow transform those into a useable font file? Please edit your question to be more clear. You don't have to provide all your dozens of images; one example is better than none...

Comment: All sorts of images mainly in common formats like jpg/jpeg/jpg. What do you mean by "raster"?

Comment: See: [Raster Graphics - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raster_graphics)

Comment: I added a hyperlink pertaining to a sample image.

Comment: @Xavierjazz This is not spam. Just a poor question stemmed from naïveté.

Answer (score 4):

It's not automated processes, but you may be able to convert the letters in the image to a font if you proceed as follows:

- Remove unnecessary regions of the image
- Convert the image to grayscale
- Clean up the image by applying suitable filters
- Copy each letter to a vector graphics programme (such as [inkscape](http://inkscape.org/))
- Use the *trace bitmap* function to generate a vector representation of the letter
- Copy or import your vectorized graphic into a font-creating program such as [fontforge](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/).

How-tos on the subject can be found [here](http://www.ehow.com/how_7394405_convert-image-true-type-font.html) or [here](http://www.ehow.com/how_7268239_convert-jpg-truetype-font.html).

Answer (score 1):

Simply put: you can't. The image file, being raster, is just a collection of pixels with colors: it has no information about which fonts are used.

What you could try is a service like [WhatTheFont](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/), which (claims to) be able to identify which font is used in a text. But (as noted in a comment), for better results, the background behind the text needs to be (mostly) the same color.

Comment: One thing about **WhatTheFont** is that the background behind the text needs to be mostly the same color.